# Show logs for commits that are in a branch

Tags: git, logging, git-branch, git-log

I have two branches master and devel, devel have usually more commits then the master. How can I get log for commits that are in devel to the point of common ancestor. Same list that's displayed when you call interactive rebase master when you're in devel branch.

this don't work:

```
git log devel..master
```

Comment: You just have the order backwards; see [Mort's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36946434/1256452) (and note the drawing: it almost always helps, with Git, if you draw a commit graph fragment first!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `merge-base` answers are not wrong *per se* but it is not necessary. This  is all you need.

```
git log master..devel
```

Think about it

```
---A---B---C---D devel
           \
            \---E---F---F master
```

`git log master..devel` means the same as `git log ^master devel`. So what is in the history of devel and not in the history of master? `D`.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I need to run this command:

```
git log $(git merge-base HEAD master)..HEAD
```

when I'm in devel branch.

Comment: I was just writing this answer when you posted :-( you bated me in about 10 sec.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the merge-base.

This is how git find the last commit which you have forked from

```
git log $(git merge-base <branch1> <branch2>)..branch2
```

Few other options:

```
git log ^<branch1> <branch2> 
git log ^<branch2> <branch1>
git diff <branch1> <branch2>
```